# Is there an equivalent in iChat to Adium's "Force old-style SSL"?

Tags: network, ichat, adium

Trying to connect to company Jabber/XMPP with iChat, I get stuck at password entering screen. Connecting with the very same info in Adium, ticking "Force old-style SSL" setting it work flawlessly. Guess it's got something to do with a self-signed SSL certificate or likewise.

How do I make the iChat client connect? Want to kick Adium to the curb for a few reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Go to iChat's Preferences > Accounts, choose the account in question, and go to the "Server Settings" tab. Make sure that "Use SSL" is checked, but change the port to 443. You should probably also turn off "Automatically find server and port" if it's on.

Comment: Tried it already, to no avail. Stucks at "Connecting…".